# Rails not loading environment.rb correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment

I recently upgraded my application from Rails version 2.1.2 to version 2.2.2. It was tested in on development and on my staging system. When I moved to production it fails to load all the way through the environment.rb file. (Why, oh why, is it always on production!?!)

Below is my environment.rb file

```
# Be sure to restart your web server when you modify this file.

# Uncomment below to force Rails into production mode when 
# you don't control web/app server and can't set it the proper way
# ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
#RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.1.0'  unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.2.2'  unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
puts "loading rails..."
# Bootstrap the Rails environment, frameworks, and default configuration
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')
puts "require boot file"
require 'socket'
puts "require socket"

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
puts "inside config section"
  # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here

  # Skip frameworks you're not going to use (only works if using vendor/rails)
  # config.frameworks -= [ :action_web_service, :action_mailer ]

  # Only load the plugins named here, by default all plugins in vendor/plugins are loaded
  # config.plugins = %W( exception_notification ssl_requirement )

  # Add additional load paths for your own custom dirs
  # config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/extras )

  # Force all environments to use the same logger level 
  # (by default production uses :info, the others :debug)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Use the database for sessions instead of the file system
  # (create the session table with 'rake db:sessions:create')
  config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
puts "setting session store type"
  # Use SQL instead of Active Record's schema dumper when creating the test database.
  # This is necessary if your schema can't be completely dumped by the schema dumper, 
  # like if you have constraints or database-specific column types
  # config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

  # Activate observers that should always be running
  # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector

  # Make Active Record use UTC-base instead of local time
  # config.active_record.default_timezone = :utc
  #config.gem "will_paginate", :source => "http://gems.rubyforge.org"


  # Action Mailer configuration - from page 567-568 of the Agile Development book
  #  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  #  
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address    => "smtp.redacted.com",
    :port       => "25",
    :domain     => "redacted.com"
  }

puts "setting smtp settings"
  # See Rails::Configuration for more options

end

puts "outside config section ... before inflectors"
# Add new inflection rules using the following format 
# (all these examples are active by default):
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
#   inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
#   inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
#   inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
#   inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )
   inflect.uncountable %w( sid fcc )
end

puts "after inflectors"
# Add new mime types for use in respond_to blocks:
# Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
# Mime::Type.register "application/x-mobile", :mobile

# Include your application configuration below
require 'will_paginate'
puts "require will paginate"

# insert at top of ActiveRecord::Base.rb
    # Indicates whether field names should be lowercased for legacy databse fields.
    # If true, the field Product_Name will be +product_name+. If false, it will remain +Product_Name+.
    # This is false, by default.
    #cattr_accessor :downcase_legacy_field_names, :instance_writer => false
    #@@downcase_legacy_field_names = false

# insert into column_methods_hash of ActiveRecord::Base.rb
#          attr_final = downcase_legacy_field_names ? attr.to_s.downcase : attr

puts "here comes the monkey patch"
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    # Indicates whether field names should be lowercased for legacy databse fields.
    # If true, the field Product_Name will be +product_name+. If false, it will remain +Product_Name+.
    # This is false, by default.
    cattr_accessor :downcase_legacy_field_names, :instance_writer => false
    @@downcase_legacy_field_names = false

  end
end

puts "monkey patch part 2"
# set all accessor methods to lowercase (underscore)
# add set_columns_to_lower to each model that needs it 
class << ActiveRecord::Base

    # Returns a hash of all the methods added to query each of the columns in the table with the name of the method as the key
    # and true as the value. This makes it possible to do O(1) lookups in respond_to? to check if a given method for attribute
    # is available.
    def column_methods_hash #:nodoc:
      @dynamic_methods_hash ||= column_names.inject(Hash.new(false)) do |methods, attr|

        attr_final = downcase_legacy_field_names ? attr.to_s.downcase : attr

        attr_name = attr_final
        methods[attr_final.to_sym]       = attr_name
        methods["#{attr_final}=".to_sym] = attr_name
        methods["#{attr_final}?".to_sym] = attr_name
        methods["#{attr_final}_before_type_cast".to_sym] = attr_name
        methods
      end
    end

   # adapted from: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowToUseLegacySchemas
    def downcase_legacy_field_methods
      column_names.each do |name|
       next if name == primary_key
       a = name.to_s.underscore

       define_method(a.to_sym) do
         read_attribute(name)
       end

       define_method("#{a}=".to_sym) do |value|
         write_attribute(name, value)
       end

       define_method("#{a}?".to_sym) do
         self.send("#{name}?".to_sym)
       end

      end
    end


end 

puts "monkey patch part 3"



ActiveRecord::Base.downcase_legacy_field_names = true

puts "monkey patch part 4"
module ActiveSupport
  module Inflector
    def textize(str)
      str.to_s.gsub(/'/, '').downcase
        #gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
        #gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
        #tr("-", "_").
        #downcase
    end

  end
end

puts "monkey patch part 5"
module ActiveSupport #:nodoc:
  module CoreExtensions #:nodoc:
    module String #:nodoc:
      module Inflections
        def textize
          Inflector.textize(self)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

###################################################################
### Code moved to the specific environment files.
### This way the schema gets reloaded on a deploy
###################################################################
## Establishes connections for the root classes of the various databases that 
## must be connected to for SUI.


puts "load the database if we are in test mode"
if RAILS_ENV == "test" then
puts "if I see this and I'm not loading test, we have a problem"
  Ird.load_database
end



puts "setting up the execption notifier"
ExceptionNotifier.exception_recipients = %w(me@redacted.com)
if RAILS_ENV == "Production"
  ExceptionNotifier.sender_address = %("SUI Service" <service@redacted.com>)
  ExceptionNotifier.email_prefix = "[SUI ERROR] "
else
  ExceptionNotifier.sender_address = %("SUI #{RAILS_ENV.to_s.humanize} Service" <service@redacted.com>)
  ExceptionNotifier.email_prefix = "[#{RAILS_ENV.to_s.humanize}: SUI ERROR] "
end


puts "local_ip function"
def local_ip
  orig, Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup, true
  UDPSocket.open do |s|
    s.connect '64.233.187.99', 1
    s.addr.last
  end
ensure
  Socket.do_not_reverse_lookup = orig
end
puts "I am located at:#{local_ip}:"
puts "environment.rb is loaded"
```

If I set the rails gem to be used to version 2.1.2 everything loads and all the `puts` statements print as expected. When I change the gem version to 2.2.2 the last statement that I see printed is "`setting smtp settings`".

When I move the `Rails::Initializer do |config|` section to the bottom it fails in ways worse than where it is right now.

The ruby version that is loaded on the system is Ruby 1.8.6 patchlevel 111. It is running on RHEL5-64bit.

I'm stumped. Ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run rake rails:update?

Also, you might want to move most of the code into config/initializers/[anything].rb, allthough I hardly think that itself will solve your problems.

Comment: Hilariously enough ... moving the extra code to initializers did the trick ... thanks for the pointer!